# Integrating the Area of a Circle

Tags: calculus, integration

So I understand that the circumference of a circle is represented by the expression $2πr$, and integrating it yields the area of the circle, represented by the expression $πr²$ - which also corresponds to the area under the graph of $2πr$.

What I'm wondering is: does integrating the area expression (and getting $\frac{πr³}{3}$) yield an expression of any significance? What would it represent, if anything? Are there any applicable patterns to be found by re-integrating in this manner?

EDIT: Notation

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Integrating $\pi r^2$ from $0$ to $r$ would represent adding up the areas of lots of circles of varying radius. If you picture these circles being stacked on top of each other then you would have... a cone. And indeed $\frac13 \pi r^3$ is the formula for the volume of a cone.

Comment: Cutting the area into annuli of infinitesimal thickness $dr$ gives them each an area $2\pi rdr$, which explains why integrating the circumference gives the area. It in turn has no analogous change-in-something interpretation. But you can go from a sphere's quadratic surface area to its cubic volume by essentially the same strategy.

Comment: What does "the area under the graph of $2πr$" mean?

Comment: @SuzuHirose $S=\int_0^R 2\pi r \, dr$ is area under graph of $f(r)=2\pi r$ from $r=0$ to $r=R$.

Comment: @Blitzer Ah, my first guess was that it would represent the volume of a cone, but the general formula for the volume of a cone is $\frac{1}{3}πr²h$, while the integral of $πr²$ is $\frac{1}{3}πr³$. Per your comment I realized that the expressions are equivalent if $h$ is equal to $r$. Why is that? I imagine it has something to do with the parameters but I can't quite wrap my head around it.